# MySQL Subquery making query super slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I've been struggling when it comes to optimizing the following query (Example 1):

```sql
    SELECT `service`.* 
    FROM
    (
          SELECT `storeUser`.`storeId`
          FROM `storeUser`
          WHERE `storeUser`.`userId` = 1
      UNION
          SELECT `store`.`storeId`
          FROM `companyUser`
            INNER JOIN `store` ON `companyUser`.`companyId` = `store`.`companyId`
          WHERE `companyUser`.`userId` = 1
      UNION
      SELECT `store`.`storeId`
      FROM `accountUser`
        INNER JOIN `company` ON `company`.`accountId` = `accountUser`.`accountId`
        INNER JOIN `store` ON `company`.`companyId` = `store`.`companyId`
      WHERE `accountUser`.`userId` = 1
    ) AS `storeUser`

        INNER JOIN `service` ON `storeUser`.`storeId` = `service`.`storeId`
    LIMIT 10;
```

The subquery should be returning something like "1","2","3,"4"

Anyway it's super slow and takes about 48 seconds to give a response, even though the subquery by itself, ran in a different console, takes about 0,0020ms to give results.

The same applies if I place the subquery inside an IN instead (Example 2):

```sql
    SELECT `service`.*
    FROM `service`
    WHERE 1
    AND `service`.`storeId` IN (
        SELECT `storeUser`.`storeId` FROM `storeUser` WHERE `storeUser`.`userId` = 1
      UNION
        SELECT `store`.`storeId` FROM `companyUser` 
            INNER JOIN `store` ON `companyUser`.`companyId` = `store`.`companyId`
        WHERE `companyUser`.`userId` = 1
      UNION
        SELECT `store`.`storeId`
        FROM `accountUser`
            INNER JOIN `company` ON `company`.`accountId` = `accountUser`.`accountId`
            INNER JOIN `store` ON `company`.`companyId` = `store`.`companyId`
      WHERE `accountUser`.`userId` = 1
    )
    LIMIT 10;
```

However if I simply put the values returned by that query, manually, it's basically instantly:

```sql
    SELECT
      `service`.*
    FROM
      `service`
    WHERE 1
    AND `service`.`storeId` IN (
      "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    )
    LIMIT 10;
```

Important to mention that'd I've reviewed the indexes in the joins and everything seems to be in place, and the EXPLAIN [query] returns a filtered score of 100 for basically everything.

Edit:

Sorry for not providing enough information before, hope this can be more helpful:

```
MySQL 5.7,
Storage engine: InnoDB

EXPLAINs
1.) StoreUser

id | select_type | table          | partitions | type | possible_keys          |  key     | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | storeUser      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY, storeUserUser |  PRIMARY | 4       | const | 1     |100.00    | Using index

2.) CompanyUser

id  | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys                              | key              | key_len | ref                         | rows  | filtered  | Extra
1   | SIMPLE      | companyUser | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,companyUserCompany,companyUserUser | companyUserUser  | 4       | const                       | 30    | 100.00    | Using index
1   | SIMPLE      | store       | NULL       | ref  | storeCompany                               | storeCompany     | 4       | Table.companyUser.companyId | 5     | 100.00    | Using index

3.) AccountUser

id  | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys           | key             | key_len | ref                         | rows  | filtered  | Extra
1   | SIMPLE      | accountUser   | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,accountUserUser | accountUserUser | 4       | const                       | 1     | 100.00    | Using index
1   | SIMPLE      | company       | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,companyAccount  | companyAccount  | 4       | Table.accountUser.accountId | 305   | 100.00    | Using index
1   | SIMPLE      | store         | NULL       | ref  | storeCompany            | storeCompany    | 4       | Table.company.companyId     | 5     | 100.00    | Using index

4.) Whole query (Example 2)

id    | select_type         | table       | partitions  | type    | possible_keys                               | key             | key_len | ref                         | rows    | filtered  | Extra
1     | PRIMARY             | service     | NULL        | ALL     | NULL                                        | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                        | 2836046 | 100.00    | Using where
2     | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  | storeUser   | NULL        | eq_ref  | PRIMARY,storeUserStore,storeUserUser        | PRIMARY         | 8       | const,func                  | 1       | 100.00    | Using index
3     | DEPENDENT UNION     | store       | NULL        | eq_ref  | PRIMARY,storeCompany                        | PRIMARY         | 4       | func                        | 1       | 100.00    | NULL
3     | DEPENDENT UNION     | companyUser | NULL        | eq_ref  | PRIMARY,companyUserCompany,companyUserUser  | PRIMARY         | 8       | const,Table.store.companyId | 1       | 100.00    | Using index
4     | DEPENDENT UNION     | companyUser | NULL        | ref     | PRIMARY,accountUserUser                     | accountUserUser | 4       | const                       | 1       | 100.00    | Using index
4     | DEPENDENT UNION     | store       | NULL        | eq_ref  | PRIMARY,storeCompany                        | PRIMARY         | 4       | func                        | 1       | 100.00    | NULL
4     | DEPENDENT UNION     | company     | NULL        | eq_ref  | PRIMARY,companyAccount                      | PRIMARY         | 4       | Table.store.companyId       | 1       | 100.00    | Using where
NULL  | UNION RESULT        | <union2,3,4>| NULL        | ALL     | NULL                                        | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL      | Using temporary
```

Comment: Please show us all the relevant info, like the schema for all these tables and the output from the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Integrate `service` into each subquery in UNION, optimize each subquery separately, then UNION, ORDER BY and LIMIT their outputs.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: "Important to mention that'd I've reviewed the indexes in the joins and everything seems to be in place,"  Please show us the indexes so that we can verify that.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't show us your indexes or EXPLAIN output, so all this is guesswork.

Clearly it's the subquery in your second example that's not optimized. That subquery is a UNION with three branches. The way you address performance trouble? Analyze and optimize each branch of the UNION separately.

You certainly need some better indexes, unless your database server is too small or misconfigured. That's very rare, so let's work on indexes.

The first branch is

```sql
 SELECT storeUser.storeId
   FROM storeUser
  WHERE storeUser.userId = 1
```

This [compound index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) [covers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) that query. Try adding it. If you have a separate index on just `userId`, drop it when you add this one.

```
ALTER TABLE storeUser ADD INDEX userId_storeId (userId, storeId);
```

The second branch is

```sql
 SELECT store.storeId
   FROM companyUser
  INNER JOIN store  ON companyUser.companyId = store.companyId
  WHERE companyUser.userId = 1
```

Subqueries with JOIN operations are a little tricker to optimize without access to EXPLAIN output, so this is guesswork. I guess these indexes will help, though. (Assuming you use InnoDB and the PK on store is storeId.)

```
ALTER TABLE companyUser ADD INDEX userId_companyId (userId, companyId);
ALTER TABLE store ADD INDEX companyId (companyId);
```

Similar analysis applies to the third branch of the UNION.

And, add this index. Your EXPLAIN points to it being missing, and so a full table scan of that large table being required.

```
ALTER TABLE service ADD INDEX storeId (storeId);
```

**Again**, helping you would be far easier if you showed us your table definitions with indexes. `SHOW CREATE TABLE service;` for example, would show us what we need for your `service` table. **Pro tip** when troubleshooting this kind of performance stuff *always doublecheck your indexes*. Ask me how I know that when you have a couple of hours to spare.

**Pro tip** Be obsessive about formatting your queries so they're readable. You, yourself a year from now, and your co-workers yet unborn need to read and reason about them. To my way of thinking that means skipping those silly backticks.

Comment: I've edited my question, hope you can find the extra info useful, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. Checked and I do have composite keys in the joint tables (companyUser, accountUser, storeUser)

Comment: Even with an `EXPLAIN`, you can't be sure which table would be looked at "first".  This has an impact on the optimal indexes.  The existence of a `WHERE` referring to only one of the tables makes it very likely that that table will be used first.

Comment: @JuanCarlos - `companyUser` seems to have 3 indexes; normally only 2 are sufficient; perhaps you have an unnecessary auto_increment?

Comment: I put in some edits here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to rethink the schema.  It seems like you need a table for "user" instead of, or in addition to, the 3 tables for different types of "users".

Meanwhile, these composite indexes are likely to help performance in either formulation:

```
storeUser:  INDEX(storeId,  userId)
storeUser:  INDEX(userId,  storeId)
service:  INDEX(storeId)
store:  INDEX(companyId,  storeId)
companyUser:  INDEX(userId, companyId)
company:  INDEX(accountId,  companyId)
accountUser:  INDEX(userId, accounted)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

In particular, `storeUser` smells like a many-to-many mapping table.  If so, see [*Many:many mapping*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for more discussion.

In general `IN( SELECT ... )` does not optimize well, but you might find otherwise for your query.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to not give more details about the schemas but I wasn't allowed to share it here, anyway, the problem happened to be elsewhere:
The service table was receiving a huge amount of requests, some actions were even locking it up, ending up on slow times whenever we were accesing that table, we have fixed our other proccess and it's working great now. Hugely appreciate your time and effort, thanks.